# Audio Embedded In Powerpoint

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint, openoffice

I have a powerpoint file which has embedded audio that I am trying to view. The problem is, I don't have powerpoint, but I do have openoffice. While I am able to view the slides in openoffice, the audio doesn't play, despite huge number of times I have clicked the play button the author has put on every slide. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If OpenOffice cannot view the file properly then the best option would probably be to use the Microsoft [PowerPoint Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13) to view the file.

The PowerPoint Viewer is likely to be the most compatible option to view files created in PowerPoint and should work on Windows XP and above.

If the audio still does not play then you may need to contact the file creator and ask them what format the audio is and how they embedded the it as you may need to find a specific codec to be able to play it.

Comment: Well, I can open the file and look through the slides; the only issue is the audio. My hope was that the issue was a stupid one--namely, that I had a feature disabled or something. Is powerpoint view free?

Comment: Okay, I downloaded PowerPoint Viewer. However, when I open the file in it, the button at the bottom right-corner to play the audio doesn't even appear. In openoffice it does appear, but when I double-click the button it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, the PowerPoint Viewer is a free tool provided by Microsoft themselves. I don't know enough about OpenOffice to know if there is some  setting to enable active content like music. I wouldn't be surprised if there was, but I don't use OO.

Comment: @noName In that case I don't think I can help, I suspect that the person you downloaded the file from used some audio format or extension that neither the viewer or OpenOffice understands and you need to find out from them what they did and why it doesn't work. If they used an embedded ActiveX object to play the audio which is not present on your machine then they need to tell you what it is.